# how to add a browser in react-electron app?

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I am recently developing desktop application using electron and reactjs. In my design, this app can display a web, allowing user to select some DOM content in this web, and automatically extract useful data inside these DOM.

But I don't know how to display a web inside electron app. I tried using a  to show the web, but when the X-Frame-Options header is set to sameorigin, it won't be display in an iframe.

Is there any other way to integrate a web inside an electron app? Especially, I need to listen the click event inside the integrated web, and I also need to access the DOM from this web.